# Create Office365 group site Web Properties programmatically with CSOM

Tags: office365, office365api, sharepoint-online, teamsite

I have been reading about updating a office 365 group site using CSOM. There are many limitations to update the group site with CSOM.

Is it possible to create web properties of office 365 group site using CSOM. I tried to create Web Properties in the office 365 group site and I am getting Access Denied exception. Any ideas about it.

Here is my code for updating web properties:

```
web.AllProperties["Type"] = "Movie";
web.Update();
web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Thanking you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking question properly will help you get better answers and help others be able to understand your question if they have a similar problem.

Comment: Thank you Marc for the Tip.